# Check health of JMS with Spring Actuator

Tags: spring-jms, spring-boot-actuator

Using JMS I have queues in between my java services.
I have several microservices running on the same machine. All in 1 Kubernetes cluster, and I would like to have some monitoring on the health of the queues, etc.

If JMS Connection are there, if messages in queues are not piling up, etc.

I'd like to have some simple healthcheck on the queue itself and I wonder if it is a good practice to define customised healthcheck endpoints using Spring Actuator or is there a better way to do this?